# How to create 10 digit random number with current date using PHP

Tags: php

I need to create 10 digit random number with current date and some input value using PHP. I am explaining my code below.

```
$current_date=date('Y-m-d');//2018-04-30
$user_input=1;
```

above data are the user input and my expected output should look below.

```
$output=1804300001
```

The random number generation format should be like this `yymmdd` with `4 digit number including user input`. Suppose user_input=1 then it should be `0001` and `user_input=12` then it should be `0012` like this.

Comment: This doesn't seem very random to me ... unlike tapir

Comment: yes..that is my generation format.

Comment: `$notRandomNumberAtAll = (new DateTime())->format('Ymd') . str_pad($userInput, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);` something like that anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
$date = new DateTime();
$input = 1;
$output = date_format($date,"ymd").sprintf('%04u', $input);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

echo getToken(1);     #201804300001
echo getToken(9999);  #201804309999
echo getToken(12345); #201804301234


function getToken($input) {
    return date('Ymd').str_pad (substr($input, 0, 4) , 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here some code for you...there many solutions.

```
$user = 12;
$date = date("ymd", $time());
echo $datum .sprintf("%04u",$user);
```

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

If using your code (`$current_date=date('Y-m-d'); //2018-04-30`):

```
$current_date = date('Y-m-d');
$user_input = 1;
$result = substr(str_replace('-', '', $current_date), 2); // Replace "-" with nothing plus remove first 2 digits
$result .= str_pad($user_input, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); // Fill in with "0" to the left
```

Might not be the prettiest code but it works fine.